# TOra new connection oracle 11g issue

Tags: oracle11g, tora

I've installed TOra client for Oracle & Oraclient 11g  as well, I'm trying to connect to remote Oracle 11g EE machine using new connection 
set HOST NAME- SQL*NET (for remote connection option i guess)
PORT & SCHEMA default as 1521 & XE respectively
given IP Address of the remote machine under DATABASE field

Getting "Check your Oracle_home& library path are correct"
checked both & are same 
any other alternatives solutions  should i be looking for ??
thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use GH for client related questions. https://github.com/tora-tool/tora/issues

Answer (score 1):

Delete the oci.dll , that would do 
NO need to edit ORACLE_HOME variable or add it

Comment: Doesn't make sense to delete the file but it worked for me when OCI.dll is delete. Any reason why that needed to be deleted as I tried to set the ORACLE_HOME and it did not work.